# How to update initialParams in React Navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have an app with array getting from storage and passing it to screen

Here is a bare version. Here if getItem is late, after rendering the screen array updates automaticly

```
import React from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

import Vocabulary from "./Screens/Vocabulary";

export default function App() {
  const [ vocabulary, setVocabulary] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@vocabulary').then(value => setVocabulary(value !=null ? JSON.parse(value) : []) )
  }, []);
    
  return (
    <VocabularyWithEdit vocabulary={vocabulary} />
  );
}
```

Then I tried to use React Navigation and set array in initialParams

```
import React from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

import Vocabulary from "./Screens/Vocabulary"

export default function App() {
  const [ vocabulary, setVocabulary] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('@vocabulary').then(value => setVocabulary(value !=null ? JSON.parse(value) : []) )
  }, []);
  const Stack = createStackNavigator()
    
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Vocabulary" component={Vocabulary} initialParams={{ vocabulary: vocabulary, str: "hey" }}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

But there array wasn't updated after rendering and set as [] or sometime i got undefinded

Please let me know how to fix it and make params update

Answer (score 3):

For anyone facing this issue, you can use `children` instead of `component` to pass props to `Screen`. This way, when the state gets updated in the `App`, the updated values will be passed to the `Screen`.

For example, instead of:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Vocabulary" component={Vocabulary} initialParams={{ vocabulary: vocabulary, str: "hey" }}/>
```

use this:

```
<Stack.Screen name="Vocabulary" children={() => <Vocabulary vocabulary={vocabulary} str="hey" />} />
```

Docs [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen#children).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest passing the vocabulary data as props to the Vocabulary component. If you prefer using the initial params, you could use [setParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#setparams) to update them later.